# group and owner permissions are wrong when php uploads files

Tags: php, linux, permissions

Not sure if this is a php configuration or linux file permission issue. The problem I'm having is when a file is uploaded through php using move_uploaded_file() into the directory which has *group* set to *ubuntu* and *owner* set to *www-data*, the uploaded file *owner* and *group* permissions change to *www-data* which causes problems for my python script to come in and perform its task on the uploaded file.

example:

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetSAVE);
```

--$targetSAVE directory is set to:

```
group: ubuntu
owner: www-data
permissions: 0755
```

--php uploaded file changes *owner* and *group* to *www-data*

```
new file changes to:
  group: www-data  <-- need this set to *ubuntu*
  owner: www-data
  permissions: 0755
```

--python script needs the group of the uploaded file set to *ubuntu*

how can I configure php to to set ownership or group of uploaded file to *ubuntu* or if this is a linux file permission issue how can i fix this?

All directories and sub directories are set to:
      group: ubuntu
      owner: ubuntu
      permissions: 0755 
 **except** the directory the files are being uploaded to, this is set to:

```
group: ubuntu
owner: www-data
permissions: 0755
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. After pulling my hair out and trying all other responses it turned out to be very simple here's what worked.

```
chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/
chmod -R 775 /var/www/
```

After that the python script executed perfectly from php.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because PHP runs as the user that runs the web server.  In effect all websites on your system will run as this user/group and therefore all have access to read eachother's files and directories created by php scripts.

Installing Apache mod [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) is probably the easiest solution to this problem.  This will allow you to run php scripts in a virtual host as a specific user and group.  You could also run PHP as a CGI and use [Apache suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) but this is a bit more complicated to set up that suPHP.

Alternatively, you should just be able to chown files from your scripts to the appropriate user/group, but the effect will be that the web server no longer can read/edit those files once you change ownership of them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'd just add a chirp directive at the end of the PHP script, if that will work in your case. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php

Look in /etc/passwd to get the numerical ID for the "ubuntu" user.

Note from the docs: "Only the superuser may change the group of a file arbitrarily; other users may change the group of a file to any group of which that user is a member."